# Getting an input from user,store and log that input

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get a value from the user (taskName input),save that value in a variable and then print the value to the console when a button (taskAdd button) is clicked.However,Once I click the button I don't get the value in my browser console window.

HTML:

```
<label for="taskName">New Task</label> 
<input type="text" id="taskName" name="task" placeholder="What is your task name?">

<input id="taskAdd" type="submit" value="Add task">
```

JavaScript:

```
function getInputValue () {
let userInput = document.getElementById("taskName").value;
console.log(userInput);
}
let addTask = document.querySelector("#taskAdd");
addTask.addEventListener("click", getInputValue());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
addTask.addEventListener("click", getInputValue());
```

with:

```
addTask.addEventListener("click", getInputValue);
```